# How to fix UILabel with wrong cutting in NSTextAlignmentRight?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have such trouble, my UILabel has NSTextAlignmentRight and I set to it text with symbol "⃏" at the end. The problem is my UILabel looks like this:

```
 -----------------                    -----------------
|             699 | but has to look: |            699 ⃏| 
 -----------------                    -----------------
```

If I try replace it with symbol "P" it's okay. Buy I need "⃏" symbol. Any solution?

Comment: How did you add the symbol? Is that currency symbol?

Comment: @Desdenova , yes it's currency symbol, but I forced to add it myself. But in the same time I have another situation, when I have to set "FREE" string to the label.

Comment: Did you check `NSNumberFormatter`? It has what you need and you can handle the `free` string easily with a simple `if` statement.

Comment: @Desdenova How can it help? You can try it yourself, just create label, set it's alignment to right and it's text to "bla-bla-bla ⃏".

Comment: Let me try it my way, I'll show you if it works. What currency is that?

Comment: @Desdenova it's Russian Ruble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
- (NSString *)printPriceWithCurrencySymbol:(CGFloat)price {

    NSNumberFormatter * numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [numberFormatter setCurrencyCode:@"RUB"];
    [numberFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ru"]];

    NSString * productPrice = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:price]];

    return productPrice;

}
```

Use it as:

```
[[self label] setText:[self printPriceWithCurrencySymbol:45.50]];
```

The problem I see is it just print "rub." in Cyrillic alphabet but not the mentioned symbol.

By judging from the below link, Ruble symbol is pretty new to the world. So I guess you'll have to wait for apple to update it's library for that.

http://www.huffingtonpost.com/huff-wires/20131211/eu--russia-ruble-symbol/?utm_hp_ref=world&ir=world